# How would you convert this multi-line fiasco to HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, haml

I can't quite wrap my mind around this.

**Original:**

```
<%=
Shasta::CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ["Customer", "Job Name", "Payment Date", "Amount", "Notes"]

  for payment in @payments
    csv << [
      payment.customer.name,
      payment.jobs.map(&:name).join(" "),
      I18n.l(payment.created_at, :format => :short_date),
      number_to_currency(payment.amount),
      payment.notes
    ]
  end
end.html_safe
%>
```

**HTML2HAML Converted it to this, but it *fails***

```
= Shasta::CSV.generate do |csv|                                        |
    csv << ["Customer", "Job Name", "Payment Date", "Amount", "Notes"] |
    for payment in @payments                                           |
      csv << [                                                         |
        payment.customer.name,                                         |
        payment.jobs.map(&:name).join(" "),                            |
        I18n.l(payment.created_at, :format => :short_date),            |
        number_to_currency(payment.amount),                            |
        payment.notes                                                  |
      ]                                                                |
    end                                                                |
  end.html_safe                                                        |
```

Comment: Whenever something like this happens, it's basically giving you a hint that you should refactor it into a helper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't exactly the answer to your question, but it's a pain to write multiple line haml statements which is why you should probably move it into a helper.

`= some_descriptive_method_name @payments`

```
def some_descriptive_method_name(payments)
  Shasta::CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << ["Customer", "Job Name", "Payment Date", "Amount", "Notes"]

    payments.each do |payment|
      csv << [
        payment.customer.name,
        payment.jobs.map(&:name).join(" "),
        I18n.l(payment.created_at, :format => :short_date),
        number_to_currency(payment.amount),
        payment.notes
      ]
    end
  end.html_safe
end
```

Comment: Yeah, any time you need more than one line in HAML, that's a sign you need a helper method.